# DateTimeParseException - Text '8/19/2020' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, string, localdate, datetimeformatter

Currently I have a method that is looking at the current date and comparing to an input date.  I'm using the java.time API.  I'm getting a DateTimeParseException where I am unable to parse the text value at index 0.  Below is my code thus far:

```
public static boolean isWeekStartFormatValid(String value) { 
     value = Util.getTrimmedValue(value);
     //In constants public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.DATE_FORMAT);
     LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
     LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);        
     if(inputDate.isAfter(currentDate) && inputDate.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
         return true;
     } 
     return false;       
 }
```

When I have the input value of 8/19/2020, I get the error below:

[err] Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8/19/2020' could not be parsed at index 0
[err]   at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
[err]   at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
[err]   at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)

Is there something I'm not doing right?  Should there be a try catch for something like this?  Not sure what to do.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Using java.time is the best approach (SO tag [java-time]). Joda-Time is not bad, only the project is in maintenance mode and not recommended for new code.

Answer (score 2):

Use java.time to get date from string:

```
LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(value,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
```

Check if input date is after current date:

```
inputDate.isAfter(currentDate)
```

Check if input date is Saturday:

```
inputDate.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY
```

Comment: Thanks!  Definitely works.  I guess Joda time is now outdated and java.time is the new standard.  My current project uses Joda time in different implementations, but no harm adding java.time to the maven POM and using it in my validations :)

Comment: Yes, Joda time was widely used before java.time was added. Now java time meet most of common needs.